# Trying to add a check before accepting a document into a collection Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a qr attendance scanner and wish to see if the scan is within the limits of the `start` and `end` time fields on my `session` Collection. If the scan takes place between the two times it should be accepted and if not it will not be accepted and a toast displayed. Currently I have it checking to see if the session exists only and not between the times of the start and end time fields. The rawData is the `sessionID` being extracted from the QR code, once extracted it checks to see if it is a valid sessionID. Now I just need to check the time of scan. Any help would be great:

```
private void barcodeRecognition(Bitmap photo) {
    FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(photo);
    FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
            .getVisionBarcodeDetector();
    Task<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>> result = detector.detectInImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionBarcode> barcodes) {

                    for (FirebaseVisionBarcode barcode: barcodes) {
                        Rect bounds = barcode.getBoundingBox();
                        Point[] corners = barcode.getCornerPoints();

                        final String rawValue = barcode.getRawValue();
                        int valueType =  barcode.getValueType();


                        mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        // TRY LINKING TO userUID on Attendance on Firebase console
                        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        final String user = currentUser.getUid(); // USED TO GET CURRENT USER UID OF PERSON LOGGED IN
                        //THIS CAN BE SET TO .getUserName() or getEmail() depending on preference

                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                        final String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());

                        FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                        DocumentReference docRef = rootRef.collection("Session").document(rawValue);
                        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                    if (document.exists()){
                                        Attendance attendance = new Attendance(rawValue,user,time);
                                        attendanceRef3.add(attendance);
                                        Toast.makeText(StudentAccount.this, "Your attendance has been recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(StudentAccount.this, "Session is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

[image]

UPDATED CODE

```
 final FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                        final DocumentReference docRef = rootRef.collection("Session").document(rawValue);
                        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                    if (document.exists()){

                                        FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                                        Query query = rootRef.collection("Session")
                                                .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("startTime", calendar.getTime())
                                                .whereLessThan("endTime", calendar.getTime());

                                        Attendance attendance = new Attendance(rawValue,user,time);
                                        attendanceRef3.add(attendance);
                                        Toast.makeText(StudentAccount.this, "Your attendance has been recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Toast.makeText(StudentAccount.this, "Session is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

EDITED CODE

```
 private void barcodeRecognition(Bitmap photo) {
    FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(photo);
    FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
            .getVisionBarcodeDetector();
    Task<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>> result = detector.detectInImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionBarcode> barcodes) {

                    for (FirebaseVisionBarcode barcode: barcodes) {
                        Rect bounds = barcode.getBoundingBox();
                        Point[] corners = barcode.getCornerPoints();

                        final String rawValue = barcode.getRawValue();
                        int valueType =  barcode.getValueType();


                        mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        // TRY LINKING TO userUID on Attendance on Firebase console
                        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        final String user = currentUser.getUid(); // USED TO GET CURRENT USER UID OF PERSON LOGGED IN
                        //THIS CAN BE SET TO .getUserName() or getEmail() depending on preference

                        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                        final String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());

                        final FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                        final DocumentReference docRef = rootRef.collection("Session").document(rawValue);
                        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                    if (document.exists()) {

                                        Date timeToCheck = calendar.getTime();
                                        Session session = document.toObject(Session.class);
                                        Date startTime = session.getStartTime();
                                        Date endTime = session.getEndTime();
                                        if (timeToCheck.after(startTime) && (timeToCheck.before(endTime))) {

                                            Attendance attendance = new Attendance(rawValue, user, time);
                                            attendanceRef3.add(attendance);
                                            Toast.makeText(StudentAccount.this, "Your attendance has been recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Toast.makeText(StudentAccount.this, "Your attendance attempt is too late", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Please add a screenshot of a single `session` document that exist in your session Collection.

Comment: session document added above Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your database structure, to filter data according to the limits of your `startTime` and `endTime` properties, please use the following queries:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query = rootRef.collection("session")
    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("startTime", timeToCheck)
    .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("endTime", timeToCheck);
```

If you don't want to be equal, you can also use the following code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query = rootRef.collection("session")
    .whereGreaterThan("startTime", timeToCheck)
    .whereLessThan("endTime", timeToCheck);
```

So using this code, you'll be able to get all `session` objects that are within the limits of the start and end time fields on your session Collection.

**Edit:**

If you want check a single document, you need to use another if statement. So inside your actual `if (document.exists()){` create another one that looks like this:

```
Attendance attendance = document.toObject(Attendance.class);
Date startTime = attendance.getStartTime();
Date endTime = attendance.getEndTime();
if(timeToCheck.after(startTime) && (timeToCheck.before(endTime)) {
    //Do what you need to do
}
```

In which `timeToCheck` is an object of type `Date` which you need to check against the actual dates from your database.

Comment: timeToCheck is showing as an unknown variable when trying to code this Alex. Also am I correct in saying this code goes after the line  if (document.exists()){

Comment: No, you should use one of those quries and make a `get()` call to get the data accoding to this query. You get an unknow variable because you should create/get one in order to make the comparison. This query means that you are searching for all session objects where `timeToCheck` is within the limits of the start and end time fields on your session Collection., right?

Comment: What I want it to do is check if the person trying to sign in is within those two time fields/limits, so for timeToCheck do I need a way to check the current time. Where does this get() call fit within the code?

Comment: Above is what I have implemented so far, I am not sure on how to make use of the query once implemented.

Comment: No no no. To be short, you want to get all the session objects that are within the limits of the start and end time fields on your session Collection or you want to check only for a single document?

Comment: I only want to check for single session document as each session document ID will be scanned individually and then checked accordingly. So when the student scans the QR code it will retrieve the document ID for each session and then check firstly that it exists and then meets the time parameters of the two time fields

Comment: The first part works fine, once the sessions documentID is gathered and placed into rawValue, it checks whether that document exists and if it does it adds the attendance record to the attendance collection. All I need now is for it to check if the time of scan is between the startTime field and endTime field.

Comment: Here is what I have tried Alex, is this what you meant. The start time and end time fields are in the session collection and not attendance also.

Comment: Change the `Attendance` with `Session`, does it work?

Comment: keeps returning the same toast explaining that I am not within the time even when changing start and end time fields in the session collection.

Comment: correction my updated code works, Alex thanks so much